# How can I view my WhatsApp messages on my Android tablet?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have an Android phone on which I use WhatsApp but for my convenience I would like to view them on my tablet which also runs Android. The tablet is wifi only so I cannot install WhatsApp on it. I'm hoping there is an app for that.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the whatsapp.apk from the Internet (its like a .exe file for Android), just search it in Google.

Comment: Note that Whatsapp can only be installed in one device only per phone number; if you put the old account on the tablet, that will invalidate the account on the phone.

Comment: Yeah, but there is no other possibility

Comment: Yep. I'm looking for a way to be able to read my whatsapp messages on the tablet. Guess nothing close to it yet.  I shall wait . Thank you guys anyways

Comment: There is a web app which allows you to use whatsapp in chrome. On pc it works, you need a app on your phone where whatsapp is installed. I don't know if this is working an a tablet